# Redirect incoming packets to loopback

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to use iptables to redirect an incoming packet on eth0 to a service listening on the loopback interface. Based on [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/) I'm attempting to craft the following rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT -o lo --to-port 80
```

but I'm getting the errror shown below:

```
Can't use -o with PREROUTING
```

The man page explains why this can't work:

```
   (REDIRECT) redirects the packet to the machine itself by changing the
   destination IP  to  the  primary  address  of  the  incoming  interface
```

How can I take incoming packets and feed them to the loopback interface?

Comment: See this iptables flowchart to understand how it works http://www.adminsehow.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/packet_flow9.png

Comment: So once a packet goes through POSTROUTING to another network card does it then enter the PREROUTING chain for the second card? Is loopback just another network interface as far as iptables is concerned?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why did you add `-o lo`? That's not necessary, doesn't work, and isn't even in the tutorial you linked to. Just remove it.

Comment: Without `-o` the packets will be redirected to the network interface they came in, which isn't what I want. `-o` doesn't work because `REDIRECT` doesn't support this usage, so what should I be using?

Comment: You should be having the service listen on the correct network interface, or use the TPROXY target.

Comment: TPROXY doesn't help me because you can't use it on packets that aren't being forwarded. I ended up hacking together a way to make the service listen on the correct interface.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution with iptables should work, but unfortunately the Linux kernel doesn't permit it, because the kernel code considers every incoming packet with destination address 127/8 a "martian" and it will not accept it.

You can see this with:

## sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.log_martians=1

To allow it traffic to 127/8 subnet use **route_localnet**

## # sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1

or

## $ echo 1 | sudo tee proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/route_localnet

and to check the setting.

## $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/route_localnet

After setting /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/route_localnet, the dnat to 127.0.0.1 will work.

Comment: Quite a dangerous option, though, because there's a reason why 127.0.0.0/8 is supposed to be non-routable: Services registering there are taking the confidentiality of said network for granted, and by opening it to the outside world this confidentiality is compromised. Better keep some firewall rules in place to avoid trouble!

As said above, a way healthier approach is to have the service in question listen on an outbound interface instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the model demonstrating [iptables and its masquerade feature](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-to-a-new-ip-using-iptables/), try redirecting to 127.0.0.1 which is your loopback, right?